# How much text I can fit in 1 kilobyte with compression?

Tags: memory, text, compression

How much text I can fit in 1 kilobyte with compression. May it be 7zip compression or etc.

Comment: Are you asking about a typical compression ratio, or some kind of maximum possible? Under what constraints and assumptions?

Comment: And also what is the entropy of the input text?

Comment: Lets just say its a plain text a Mark Twain novel

Answer (score 0):

It's an honest question . As usual, the answer is "it depends". Some text is very compressible (e.g. A string of zeros), others are not. (e.g. random data).

Comment: Lets just say its a plain text a Mark twain novel

Comment: Again, it depends. Which novel? some novels are more compressible than others.

Comment: The Adventures Of Tom Sawyer gutenberg edition. How many you can fit in in 1KB? from beginning to the end.
  https://www.gutenberg.org/files/74/74-h/74-h.htm

Comment: Give it a try. Zip that novel and see what you get.

Comment: I was hoping someone else toil with above effort but anyways I can try...